# Решение проблемы с wsgi-скриптом/Apache2

Tags: python, apache, веб-сервер, wsgi, astra-linux

Имеется небольшой тестовый проект на django 2.0.4, в нем же стандартный wsgi.py и мой собственный myapp.wsgi, в который я положил скрипт из стандартного примера, а именно

```
def application(environ, start_response):
status = '200 OK'
output = b'Hello World!'

response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                    ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
start_response(status, response_headers)

return [output]
```

На что firefox мне выдает следующее:

> Ошибка в типе содержимого
>   Страница, которую вы пытаетесь просмотреть, не может быть показана, так как она использует неверную или неподдерживаемую форму компрессии.
>   Пожалуйста, свяжитесь с владельцами веб-сайта и проинформируйте их об этой проблеме.

Есть подозрения, что проблема в кодировках, но поиски ничего не дали, а error.log остается пустым.Тут стоит оговориться, что поднять сервер я пытаюсь на Astra Linux SE 1.6. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем может быть связана такая проблема?

wsgi.py

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite1.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

apache2.conf

```
ServerName example.com
ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
In# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noetclude ports.conf
    <Directory /home/astra-admin/1/mysite1>
    <Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted 
    </Files>
    </Directory>    
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/astra-admin/1/mysite1>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /home/astra-admin/1/mysite1/myapp.wsgi
<Directory /home/astra-admin/1/mysite1>
    <Files myapp.wsgi>
    Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
<Directory /home/astra-admin/1/mysite1>
<Files wsgi.py>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Comment: И покажите настройки сайта из апача

Comment: Ну это я могу...